# Add ripple to ClickableText annotatedString in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add ripple effect to custom styled annotatedString inside ClickableText. Here's the code:

```
  val annotatedText = buildAnnotatedString {
        append("SomeText ")
        pushStringAnnotation(
            tag = "privacy",
            annotation = "privacy",
        )
        append("Privacy Policy")
        pop()
    }

    ClickableText(
        text = annotatedText,
        onClick = { offset ->
           annotatedText.getStringAnnotations(
                tag = "privacy",
                start = offset,
                end = offset,
            ).firstOrNull()?.let {
                // onClick
            }
        },
    )
```

Is there an elegant way to add ripple when pressed on the annotated text "Privacy Policy"?

Comment: I think they haven't exposed any interaction source in ClickableText. Why don't you try clickable modifier?

Comment: @imn, i have the same problem. i think that reason why clickable modifier is not a solution is that text maybe too big, too difficult, and, for example, you can have some link in center of that text, and you want to change style of that link after tapping on it. then i don't have solution, don't know how to do that too: `RippleTheme` really can't be provided to `pushStyle` function when building `AnnotatedString`.